# How do I interpret this section of the datasheet?

Tags: datasheet

[image]

Why are there two identical - not once but twice, test conditions / comments but the min, typ, max have conflicting data? How the heck am I supposed to interpret it? Is this just an error?

Comment: 17.5uA max, next line same test condition, 40uA max.

Comment: No idea. You might want to provide a link to the whole datasheet to know what it means.

Comment: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/aducm355.pdf

Comment: It looks like they may have meant to have one range for "normal indoor use" between, say, 0C and 40C and another over the entire advertised temperature range (only specifying a maximum is a bit of a giveaway).  I would contact the manufacturer to be sure.

Comment: Good insight, I was only asking to see if there was some common knowledge involved within this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a bit of mistake on Analog's part.  From this [datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADP165_166.pdf) for a random Analog LDO, you can see that they give typical and maximum current consumption at 25C and a maximum current over the entire operating range:
[image]
It *appears* as though the first current entry in your datasheet is probably measured at room temperature and the second entry is for -40/+60C but I would double check with Analog if it's important.